# ISA relationship ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship, rdbms

I want to add different type of departments to an entity called department in a ER diagram.Can I use **ISA relationship** for it.there are more than 2 departments.does **ISA relationship** can have more than 2 subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A supertype can have any number of subtypes. However, it's only useful to define subtypes if they'll have their own attributes or relationships. If not, a type attribute is sufficient.